# Защита от ввода отрицательного числа

Tags: python

Код выводит возраст:

```
def retrieve_age(person):
      try: 
        return int(person["age"])
      except ValueError: 
        print("Вы некорректно ввевили возраст")
print(retrieve_age({"name" : "Max", "age": 5}))
```

Как сделать защиту от отрицательного ввода?

Comment: А зачем тут использовать исключение если достаточно просто сделать условие проверки на отрицательность?

Comment: Не забывайте [принимать ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), иначе вам могут перестать помогать :)

Answer (score 4):

Получить значение, проверить на отрицательное число и выбросить исключение:

```
def retrieve_age(person):
    try:
        age = int(person["age"])
        if age < 0:
            raise ValueError()
        return age
    except ValueError: 
        print("Вы некорректно ввели возраст")

print(retrieve_age({"name" : "Max", "age": 5}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот еще способ, если очень хочется:

```
def retrieve_age(person):
    try:
        age = int(person["age"])
        assert age > 0
        return int(person["age"])
    except AssertionError:
        return "Вы некорректно ввевили возраст"

print(retrieve_age({"name": "Max", "age": -55}))
```